# Slightly pedantic question: which is more efficient?

Tags: c++

Which is more efficient? Or are they both equally efficient?
What is going on in the underlying architecture in the starred lines?

**(1)**

```
for(int i = m_size; i > index; --i)
{
     int k = normalize(i);             ***
     m_data[k] = m_data[k - 1];
}
```

or **(2)**

```
int k = 0; ***

for(int i = m_size; i > index; --i)
{
     k = normalize(i);             ***
     m_data[k] = m_data[k - 1];
}
```

Comment: You can `cc -S file.c` to check the generated assembly ("underlying architecture"). But unless you're writing game engines or device drivers, you should typically worry more about readability than efficiency.

Comment: Awesome! I had no idea you could do that!

Comment: `k` doesn't need to be iniitalized in the second example. After removing that, any sensible compiler will generate identical code for both. Specifically, the allocation and deallocation of `k` inside the loop does not require any machine instructions: the stack frame is defined for the entire method on entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't get bothered with such micro-level optimization. Let the compiler/optimizer do it for you. As per C++ style, the 2nd approach is better as it declares the variable close to the usage (as discussed in "Code Complete" book). Other than C style, the first approach is good if you want to use the variable after the loop.

Do note that the function `normalize`, the type of `m_data`, the operator `[]` involved, etc. all play role in optimization. Size of data, parallelism, processor architecture also plays an important role in the program's run time performance.

Answer (score 4):

snippet #1 is more efficient for a naive compiler because the second snippet requires the loading of 0 in the variable k.

A good compiler will recognize that k is not used before the loading of k in the for loop and will optimize away the extra assignment.

You can use snippet 2 without loading the 0: `int k;`

Comment: Would it still be no difference in efficiency in a good compiler if I remove the initialization?

Comment: You would have to look at the assembler.  some compilers would catch it, others might not.  I would declare the int k above the loop without initialization, but the compiler should not care.

Comment: But in theory, in snippet 1, isn't it recreating an int at every iteration, since k technically goes out of scope at the end of the loop? Surely a compiler could optimize this out, but I thought in theory it was better to do snippet 2 because of this.

Comment: @Chipster: I agree that you can look at it that way.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say what's "going on in the underlying architecture" without knowing what architecture you're talking about. But in general, any question of the "which is more efficient" kind can only ever really be answered in the obvious way: By measuring which version ends up being more efficient in your particular application…

Note that any remotely useful compiler should turn both your examples into exactly the same machine code…

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem of efficiency. The first approach is better one because it uses RAII (Resource Allocation Is Initialization) approach. The second one is more C-style. You should declare variables when you use it, not in the beginning of the functional block. See this example:

```
void f1(bool use)
{
    ComplexObject c; // creating an object that has very costly, time-and-memory-consuming initialization

    if (! use)
        return;
    c.someFunction();
}
```

See what I mean ?